# How put data in app.blade.php from controller in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I need to put some dynamic data from controller to `app.blade.php`, but I can't find any controller. Where I should do this? Thanks

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load a view from any controller, say for eg. `HomeController`. There it can load a view file eg `home.blade.php`.Which usually extends the `app.blade.php`.

So you can pass data from `HomeController` to the view.

```
    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Show the application dashboard.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
         */
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            return view('home', ['foo' => $request->session()->get('key');
] );
        }
    }
```

`home.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

`app.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        <div> {{$foo}} </div>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to add dynamic data like I have value in session and put this value in app.blade file.so how can add this

Comment: Still possible, I wil update the naswer.